# Should I use one HTTP request to check if an action is possible, then another to perform that action, or shoud I bundle that into one request?

Tags: rest, http, backend

I'm making a website where users are able to join game rooms up to a certain number of players. I'm not sure how I should handle a user trying to join a room. I've thought of two ideas:

1. Make a request to the backend to check whether the room is full or not, then make a request to add the user to the room, only if the first request returns a positive response
2. Make only one request that does all the logic in the backend, then either adds the user to the room if it's not full or returns some kind of message to signify to the frontend that the room is full.

The second approach seems more efficient, with less back-and-forth between the frontend and backend, but it also creates inconsistency in the response format. What's the better practice?
If that's relevant, I'm using a MERN stack with a REST API, but I think my question is more of a general one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important thing to notice is that you are in a distributed system - the client is not *locking* the "room" against other edits.  In effect, that means you are talking about [data on the outside](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807): the information as seen by the web client is stale (it's at least nanoseconds old) and subject to change.

So there's a race condition - by the time the "add" request arrives, the availability of the room may have changed.

Which means that your protocol for the "add" request needs some provision for the not-so-happy-path.  And the client implementation will need to handle the case where the add request does produce the desired response.

So everybody has to handle that case anyway; the pre-flight check doesn't actually save you any work.

So your second approach is fine.

> but it also creates inconsistency in the response format.

Not really - again, you have to handle the failure modes.  So now we're just quibbling about which data/meta-data is used as the predicate where the client code has to branch.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice would be to go with option #2. There is no need to make two requests if the room is not full.  You just need to determine the most appropriate response for if the room is full.  You can either return a 200 (OK) and with some meaningful error code in the response body that your client knows means the room is full; or go with a 500-level code, such as 503 (Service Unavailable) to indicate that the room cannot be joined.  Since a room being full is not a client related "error," a 400-level code would not be appropriate.